# pojo attributes handling 2 types

Tags: java

Is this possible for an attribute to handle 2 types in a pojo class, like if we are trying to parse `json` and `json` giving `String` sometimes and sometimes `String []`. How can we handle it ?

```
private String a1; 
private String a1[];
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you want to accomplish ? Is it purely about JSON parsing ?

Comment: We want to convert json file to java object , sometimes in one attributes we are getting Array : [{}] and sometimes in the same attribute we are getting {} . As we result when we are trying to use jackson object mapper it is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, Java does not support dynamic types so a property/variable can have only one type that should be specified in compile time and is not changeable. Even with the support of dynamic type systems, the code you specified would not work because it ends up in a name conflict. You can try other JVM languages like Groovy which support dynamic type system like this:

```
def a1 = "sample string"
a1 = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
```

As you can see the type of the variable a1 is first String and then an array of string is assigned to it.